# Parse content and push in array

Tags: php

I fetches content from my .php file and want to push in an array the fetched result is something like:

```
//english error

$lang['error_incorrect_login'] = "The username or password doesn't match. Please try again";

$lang['error_user_exist'] = "The Username already exist in database. Please try using a different Username";

$lang['error_email_exist'] = "Email address already exist in database";
```

this is the actual content of my .php file

and I need result array like:

```
array(
    ['error_incorrect_login'] = "The username or password doesn't match. Please try again",
    ['error_user_exist'] = "The Username already exist in database. Please try using a different Username",
    ['error_email_exist'] = "Email address already exist in database"
);
```

I actually want to parse

```
$lang['error_incorrect_login'] = The username or password doesn't match. Please try again";
```

type of statements & push in to an array like.

```
array(
        ['error_incorrect_login'] = "The username or password doesn't match. Please try again",
        ['error_user_exist'] = "The Username already exist in database. Please try using a different Username",
        ['error_email_exist'] = "Email address already exist in database"
    );
```

Comment: $lang *is* in the form you want, print_r gives exactly this.

Comment: well it is in my .php file as a content. I am using $contents = file($my_php_file); and if use foreach($contents as $b => $v){
  debug($v);
 } above result appears

Comment: Surely you're just after `include(file.php); foreach($lang...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks friends I used `explode` over **'='** like this:

```
$lang = '$lang';

$content = array(); 
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $line = trim(fgets($fp));
            if ( ($line != "<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');") && ($line != "") ) {

                $explode = explode("=", $line);
                $content['log'][] = str_replace( "']", "", str_replace( $lang . "['", "", trim( $explode[0] ) ) );

                if (!isset($explode[1]))
                    $msg = "";
                else
                    $msg = str_replace( ";", "", str_replace( "'", "", trim( $explode[1] ) ) );

                $content['msg'][] = $msg;           
            }
        }
```